# minesweeper floodfill using c++

Tags: c++

Here is the relevant code in the `mainwindow.cpp` file, the whole `mainwindow.cpp` [github link](https://github.com/ekato993/mine/blob/main/mainwindow.cpp)

First I generate 10x10 pushbutton grid, none of the cells is revealed (bool). Then I generate 10 mines ("*") and the numbers. If I click on cell (pushbutton), I call `clickCell(int row, int col)` function.

The problem is that, if I click on a cell that contain "0", I stuck in an infinity loop due to the recursion

```
QVector<QVector<QPair<QPushButton*,bool>>> buttons;

void MainWindow::clickCell(int row, int col) {

    //reveal the cell
    buttons[row][col].first->setStyleSheet("background-color: grey; color: red; font-size: 24px");
    buttons[row][col].second = true;

    if(buttons[row][col].first->text() == "0") {
        floodFill(row,col);
    }
}

void MainWindow::floodFill(int row, int col) {

    if(buttons[row][col].first->text()=="0") {

        if(row > 0 && buttons[row-1][col].first->text() != "*") {
            buttons[row-1][col].first->setStyleSheet("background-color: grey; color: red; font-size: 24px");
            buttons[row-1][col].second = true;
            floodFill(row-1,col);
        }

        if(row < 9 && buttons[row+1][col].first->text() != "*") {
            buttons[row+1][col].first->setStyleSheet("background-color: grey; color: red; font-size: 24px");
            buttons[row+1][col].second = true;
            floodFill(row+1,col);
        }
        if(col < 9 && buttons[row][col+1].first->text() != "*") {
            buttons[row][col+1].first->setStyleSheet("background-color: grey; color: red; font-size: 24px");
            buttons[row][col+1].second = true;
            floodFill(row,col+1);
        }

        if(col > 0 && buttons[row][col-1].first->text() != "*") {
            buttons[row][col-1].first->setStyleSheet("background-color: grey; color: red; font-size: 24px");
            buttons[row][col-1].second = true;
            floodFill(row,col-1);
        }
    }
    else {
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, for row = 1 and both the element and the element above being 0 you'll go up first and then immediately go back down, then go back up again and back down again... You need to keep track of the cells you've already visited to avoid this...

Comment: oh okey, now that is working for me

Comment: other problem is that when I click on a cell, the corners not reveal.

Answer (score 1):

Your recursion keeps going and has no way to stop. You should ignore the already revealed cells:

```
   QVector<QVector<QPair<QPushButton*,bool>>> buttons;

void MainWindow::clickCell(int row, int col) {

    //reveal the cell
    buttons[row][col].first->setStyleSheet("background-color: grey; color: red; font-size: 24px");

    if(buttons[row][col].first->text() == "0") {
        floodFill(row,col);
    }
    buttons[row][col].second = true; // let's move that after the fill
}

void MainWindow::floodFill(int row, int col) {

    if(!buttons[row][col].second) {

        buttons[row][col].first->setStyleSheet("background-color: grey; color: red; font-size: 24px");
        buttons[row][col].second = true;

        if (buttons[row][col].first->text()=="0") {

            if(row > 0 && buttons[row-1][col].first->text() != "*") {
                floodFill(row-1,col);
            }         
            if(row < 9 && buttons[row+1][col].first->text() != "*") {
                floodFill(row+1,col);
            }
            if(col < 9 && buttons[row][col+1].first->text() != "*") {
                floodFill(row,col+1);
            }

            if(col > 0 && buttons[row][col-1].first->text() != "*") {
                floodFill(row,col-1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is only reveal the zeroes, it should reveal all each number adjacent to the zeroes, and there is problem with the  corners, it should reveal the cell to north east, NW, SE, SW.

Comment: I have made an edit to my original question.

Comment: @ekato so if it's not a zero, you want to reveal it but not recurse, see edit

Comment: @ekato adding NE,NW,SE,SW directions to the recursion left as exercise for the reader (col+1 & row+1 etc.)

Comment: I have added NE, , ...., nothing change, I have tried it with your method, and with my method.  I have edited my post as well.

Comment: @ekato I think anyone else wishing to solve your problem will get confused by the edits. Make sure your question still makes sense to an uninitiated reader and it is clear which code you are using and what problem it has. (BTW I have no idea what "nothing changed" means in the context of my answer, I doubt it's infinite recursion)

Comment: Nothing change means that everthing is still the same. There is no problem with the infinity loop.

Comment: SE,SW,NW,NS make no different